# Java Plugin Has Security Vunerabilities

Tags: java, security, web, applet, manifest

I'm trying to deploy a java applet on a webpage and I constantly recieve the warning "The plugin has security vunerabilites - [Activate Java]". I'm not talking about the popup dialog just the embedded security warning.

---

[image]

---

I have noticed that I recieve this warning even on oracle's example applet pages. I am self-signing the applet and I've added most of the manifest attributes for security. **So my question is this: If I'm self-signing my application will I ever be able to bypass this security warning?**

If someone is feeling very generous can they please give me the manifest attributes needed for a fully secure java applet? Meaning an applet which will not show a warning.

Much appreciation!

Comment: What happens when you click the "Activate Java" link?  I think all Java applets are now suspect and require a user's permission to execute.  I have an unsigned applet that gets the same message.  It works after I give it permission in later prompts.

Comment: This is not connected to the Applet itself. The Java plugin itself is considered unsecure and Firefox requires the users to explicitly activate it if they want to take the responsibility.

Comment: *"I am self-signing the applet.."*  Only applets signed using a certificate issued by a CA are likely to be launched in a web browser these days, and even then it is a hit and miss affair.  FF and Chrome are set to remove **all** support for applets.